# How to test registration form in Laravel 5 with Behat ? How to write a feature?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, bdd, behat

I have to **test my Larravel** application **using Behat** ,and
I have written Laravel application that satisfies:

> A user opens the web application in his/her browser
>
> The user enters his/her name and email into the registration form
>
> The user clicks the 'Register' button below the form
>
> The application registers the user (name/email) in the database
>
> The application redirects the user to a page that contains a “Thank
>   you” message.***

I have to write **Behat features** ,but I don-t know where to start? I have read about **BDD** but still confused.

Also it should be **covered with unit tests** for basic things like non-UTF-8
input, empty forms and non-string input.

**Something like this?**

```
    Feature: Registation form
        In order to test register on this site
        As a visitor
        I need to fill in the necessary info
    Scenario: 
        Given I am on the homepage
        When I fill in "username" with "Chrismo" 
        And I fill in "email" with "chris@chrismo.com"
        Then I should see "THank you"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write all your feature files on the `features` folder.

For example, if you want to write a feature for `functional` testing, you can create a file named `welcome.feature` and put it in `features/functional` folder.

And for Unit testing, Behat doesn't have assertions per-se. So, you may want to use PHPUnit's assertions. As PHPUnit comes bundled with new Laravel apps, it's already available, and all one needs to do to access the assertions is import the class in the FeatureContext class of Behat, as follows:

`use PHPUnit_Framework_Assert as PHPUnit;`

You will then have access to assertions and write your tests.

EDIT: Here's a detailed tutorial which you can follow: https://blog.vinelab.net/building-reliable-apis-using-bdd-behant-laravel-5-949156a37e66#.yv89tcqkw

Answer (score 0):

I have read about  levels of testing : Acceptance , Functional ,Integration and Units.
I'm not sure what it the difference between the first two . Tell me If I-m wrong but on the above example

Acceptance level would be creating features like this :

```
Feature: Registation form
    In order to test register on this site
    As a visitor
    I need to fill in the necessary info
Scenario: 
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I fill in "name" with "Chrismo" 
    And I fill in "email" with "chris@chrismo.com"
    And I press "Register"
    Then I should see "THank you".
```

And  on the functional ,what must be done? Maybe "somehow" checking is the user saved in the users table(database) ?

Comment: Ok, thank you.
Here are some more links:

  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-bdd-and-you-lets-get-started--cms-22155

https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-bdd-in-laravel